# Python - Add words from string list that begin with a specific char

Tags: python, string, char

Ok, stuck on another Python Question. I have tried this a few times, but can't seem to figure it out.

Question: Implement a function startString( char, stringlist) that returns a list of all strings in the list that begin with the character char.

```
startString('s',["simple", "to", "do", "some","things"])
```

This is what I have tried thus far and I know it doesn't work:

```
def startString(char, stringlist):
    newlist = []
    for i in stringlist:
        if stringlist[0] == char:
            newlist.append(stringlist)
    print newlist
```

Thank for any help that is offered.

Comment: It is, but I have been stuck on it for a few days now. I use this site to get ideas and work from there.

Comment: No problem, please just remember to tag them as such - we're happy to help, but not to do your homework for you.  :)

Comment: Hint: you're testing stringlist[0] == char.  You might want to add a "print stringlist[0], char" command to see what's going on.  Hint #2: what are you appending to newlist?

Comment: lol, ok, thanks. Yeah, this site has helped me a bit with some programming. I am in a class that I will use 7 different languages in one semester and I have to learn the syntax and submit the program within 2 weeks of getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
def startString(char, stringlist):
    newlist = []
    for string in stringlist:
        if string.startswith(char):
            newlist.append(string)
    print newlist
```

Comment: I tried this set of code to see if it would work and I got this:

   `'startstring('s',["simple","to","do","some","things"])
    [['simple', 'to', 'do', 'some', 'things'], ['simple', 'to', 'do', 'some', 'things']]`

Comment: `startString("s",["simple","to","do","some","things"]` myoutput is:
`['simple', 'some']`

Comment: @RanRag That’s because I edited your answer 7 minutes ago. `:P`

Comment: Lol, i didn't noticed. Thanks for the edit. I just copied `seiryuu's` code and added `startswith()` to it.

Comment: Ok, I messed around with it and the `newlist.append(stringlist)` needed to be 'newlist.append(string)`.

Comment: @RanRag Thanks, I accepted it and works great now. Of course, I twicked some names, but the overall worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Guessing it might be homework, we'll start with some easy things.

1. You can create new lists in Python with a List Comprehension.

   `newList = [item for item in oldList]`
2. You can index into Strings the same way you do lists.  This is equivalent to the `.startswith()` method from a string.

   `firstChar = inputString[0]`
3. You can use conditions in list comrpehensions to control what items show up in the new list.

   `newList = [item for item in oldList if <logic test>]`
4. Depending on how you're being graded, remember to `return` the new list, not `print` it.  If the grading is done in any way that's automated the difference will be noticeable.

Reviewing your provided sample code further, it looks like your difficulty is probably in this line:

```
if stringlist[0] == char:
```

Here, you're retrieving the first value from the passed in list, not the first character of the string you're attempting to test.  That would be enough to cause the trouble for you. Additionally, you probably don't want this line:

```
newlist.append(stringlist)
```

That's going to put the entire input list into your output list.  You probably want:

```
newlist.append(i)
```

A lot of those details are found in other answers / suggestions as well.

Comment: So, is this 3 different lines of code? I am not sure I am grasping the concept.

Comment: @seiryuu10 - Those three lines are all valid separately (except for `<logic test>`, which you'd replace with an actual test). Providing copy/paste code for homework is generally bad form - I'd rather point you to what's going wrong than just solve it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did search the concepts and I understand more now. I am just happy this is the only homework using python, but I might explore this more on my own.

Comment: @seiryuu10 - Happy to help, and glad you found what you needed.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Python List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). This "function" would normally be written in a single line with python.  You also want to look at [the .startswith method of strings](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Answer (score 0):

The `for i in stringlist` iterates through your list with each element being represented as the variable `i`. Take a look at what you're testing within the loop and see if it's truly what you want to check. What is `stringlist[0]` really?

Answer (score 0):

use `mystring.startswith()`. [Check docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

Then use, for example, a list comprehension using startswith to filter list items

Comment: Using mystring[0] is equivalent, and he's already got that in place.

Comment: @g.d.d.c yes it is the same but `startswith` in this case produces a very readable, understandable line of code --> `item ... if item.startswith('s')`. I think it is worth to show it to the OP

Comment: I agree this is much better but technically it's not equivalent (e.g. `startString('si', ['simple'])` will return an empty list with his original (corrected) code).

Comment: Just as a curiosity: for the comparison, slicing is 5 times faster than startswith (py3.2, timeit)

Comment: You're correct - `[0]` is only equivalent if the test string is length 1.  Otherwise, `startswith` is more appropriate unless you're doing a slice with the length of the string to check.  The speed difference is interesting though.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in stringlist:
   if stringlist[0] == char:
```

The second line says that instead of looking at the first letter of one of the strings, you're just looking at the first word in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over stringlist, but then you check, if the first element of your string list equals to `char`.  You should change `stringlist` to `i` in your `for`-loop.  (though it may be nicer using `filter()`.